# Какое окружение лучше использовать для Laravel?

Tags: laravel

В тестовых целях использовал Laravel на Debian.
Однако в документации также настоятельно рекомендуют VMWare + Homstead и пр. виртуальные технологии.
Планирую разрабатывать большой проект и тут стала дилемма: как лучше всего организовать окружение.
У кого какой есть опыт использования различных окружений? Интересует прежде всего скорость для нагруженных проектов, да и другие критерии также будут интересны.

Comment: laragon - мне нравится.

Answer (score 2):

VMWare + Homstead это более для разработки. Лично я работаю под виндой и юзаю опенсервер. А вот проды нужно уже что-то линуксоводобное. Опять же каждому что больше нравится.
Если проект высоконагруженный будет рекомендую сразу продумать хорошую расширяемую архитектуру. Все холодно/горячие данные по S3 распихать. Начать можно с ВПС/ВДС, если не будет хватать мощностей тоже можно перебраться на Амазон.
Для среднего проекта вполне хватит ВПСки под убунтой/ЦентОС/дебиан, нгиникс, пхпфпм, редис/мемкешед
По поводу БД тоже сложно сказать, постгрес или MySQL/Maria

Answer (score 0):

Docker считаю что будет лучший выбор.

Но если не хотите его использовать, то для локальной разработки, не нужны OpenServer, Laragon и Homestead. Можете установить php, postgresql сервер (или mysql) и redis наверное понадобится. И всё, запускаете `php artisan serve` и работаете.

А на продакшин сервер, если нету сисадмина в команде, то можете использовать Laravel Forge.